# C# PLINQ Ошибка

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

Всем привет, у меня такая задача я считываю большой txt файл и работаю с каждым словом в нем. Без многопоточности всё работает как надо. Но я хочу распараллелить её. Параллельно обрабатывать несколько слов.
За обработку каждого слова отвечает void функция принимающая string - void

```
text.AsParallel()
                .Select(str => str.ToUpper())
                .Where(str => str.Length >= countCharacter &&
                                    Regex.IsMatch(str, "[A-Z]+"))
                .ForAll(str =>
                {
                    checkNode(str);
                });

private void checkNode(string node)
        {
            int size = node.Length;
            int countSkip = 0;
            while (countSkip + countCharacter <= size)
            {
                string characters = getConcatStrings(node.Skip(countSkip).Take(countCharacter).ToList());
                countSkip++;
                if (pairs.ContainsKey(characters))
                    pairs[characters]++;
                else
                    pairs.TryAdd(characters, 1);
            }
        }
```

1. Без расспараллеливания

```
foreach (var str in text
                       .Select(str => str.ToUpper())
                       .Where(str => str.Length >= countCharacter &&
                                     Regex.IsMatch(str, "[A-Z]+"))
               checkNode(str);
```

2. Тоже самое пытаюсь сделать, но уже с PLINQ

```
 text.AsParallel()
                .ForAll(str => 
                {
                    str = str.ToUpper();
                    if (str.Length >= countCharacter 
                                        && Regex.IsMatch(str, "[A-Z]+"))
                        checkNode(str);
                });
```

Во втором случае выдает ошибку

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Сообщение = Произошла одна или несколько ошибок.
  Источник = System.Core
  Трассировка стека:
   в System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTaskGroupState.QueryEnd(Boolean userInitiatedDispose)
   в System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTask.SpoolForAll[TInputOutput,TIgnoreKey](QueryTaskGroupState groupState, PartitionedStream`2 partitions, TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
   в System.Linq.Parallel.DefaultMergeHelper`2.System.Linq.Parallel.IMergeHelper<TInputOutput>.Execute()
   в System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute()
   в System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitions, Boolean ignoreOutput, ParallelMergeOptions options, TaskScheduler taskScheduler, Boolean isOrdered, CancellationState cancellationState, Int32 queryId)
   в System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedStreamMerger`1.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitionedStream)
   в System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.WrapPartitionedStream[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream, IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient, Boolean preferStriping, QuerySettings settings)
   в System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.ChildResultsRecipient.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream)
   в System.Linq.Parallel.ListQueryResults`1.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient)
   в System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient)
   в System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.GetOpenedEnumerator(Nullable`1 mergeOptions, Boolean suppressOrder, Boolean forEffect, QuerySettings querySettings)
   в System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.RunSynchronously()
   в System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ForAll[TSource](ParallelQuery`1 source, Action`1 action)
   в TaskTextWorker.TextWorker.Start() в C:\Users\danil\source\repos\TaskTextWorker\TaskTextWorker\TextWorker.cs:строка 43
   в TaskTextWorker.TextWorker.GetStatistics(List`1 text, Int32 countTop, Int32 countCharacter) в C:\Users\danil\source\repos\TaskTextWorker\TaskTextWorker\TextWorker.cs:строка 28
   в TaskTextWorker.Program.Main(String[] args) в C:\Users\danil\source\repos\TaskTextWorker\TaskTextWorker\Program.cs:строка 17

Внутреннее исключение 1:
ArgumentException: Длина результирующего массива недостаточна. Проверьте значения destIndex и length, а также нижние границы массива.
```

Вопрос что делать и почему так ?

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Дело точно не в функции `checkNode`, которую вы совершенно правильно не включили в вопрос.

Comment: добавил реализация метода  checkNode()

Comment: что такое `pairs`?

Comment: private Dictionary<string, ushort> pairs = new Dictionary<string, ushort>();

Comment: Тут больше у меня вопрос как парраллельно брать несколько слов из текса и также парралельно использовать на них функцию checkNode(string)

Comment: Метод `checkNode` не является потокобезопасным, потому что использует внешние источники данных, ко орые наверняка не поддерживают безопасную работу из нескольких потоков.

Answer (score 0):

Так я ипользовал контейнеры List и Dictionary<string, ushort> они являются не потоко безопасными, поэтому когда заменил на ConcurrentDictionary<string, ushort> и на Dictionary<string, ushort>. Насколько моё решение правильно с точни зрения вычислений пока не знаю, но хотяб собирается и работает.

Comment: `if (pairs.ContainsKey(characters)) pairs[characters]++; else pairs.Add(characters, 1);` - небезопасно даже с `ConcurrentDictionary`: 1) первый поток, проверяет ключ, ключа нет 2) второй поток в то же время проверяет ключ, ключа нет 3) первый поток добавляет запись в словарь 4) второй поток добавляет запись в словарь и ловит исключение, потому что ключ уже существует. Ну или покажите код в ответе, который круто работает.

Comment: Насколько круто не круто, но работает private ConcurrentBag<string> text; private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ushort> pairs; - контейнеры